# Where to find CUDA's cutil_math.h?

Tags: cuda

The [CUDA FAQ](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-faq) says:

> CUDA defines vector types such as float4, but doesn't include any
>   operators on them by default. However, you can define your own
>   operators using standard C++. The CUDA SDK **includes a header
>   "cutil_math.h"** that defines some common operations on the vector
>   types.

However I can not find this using CUDA SDK 5.0. Has it been removed/renamed?

I've found a version of the header [here](http://code.google.com/p/cudpp/source/browse/trunk/common/inc/cutil_math.h?r=157). How is it related to the one that's supposed to come with SDK?

Comment: The cutil functionality was deleted from the CUDA 5.0 Samples (i.e. the "SDK").   You can still [download a previous SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) and compile it under CUDA 5, you should then have everything that came with previous SDK's.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take it for an answer. Any ideas why it got discontinued?

Comment: It is replaced by other header files like math_helper.h and they are still in samples\common\inc directory.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The cutil functionality was deleted from the CUDA 5.0 Samples (i.e. the "SDK"). You can still [download a previous SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) and compile it under CUDA 5, you should then have everything that came with previous SDK's.

The official notice was given by nvidia in the CUDA 5.0 release notes (CUDA_Samples_Release_Notes.pdf, installed with the samples).  As to why, I imagine that the nvidia sentiment regarding cutil probably was something like what is expressed [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/486454/cuda-programming-and-performance/cutil-header-not-present-at-all-no-its-not-an-environment-variable-error/) "not suitable for use in a real application. It is completely unsupported"  but people were using it in real applications.  So one way to try put a stop to that is to delete it, I suppose.  That's just speculation.

Note some additional useful info provided in the release notes:

> CUTIL has been removed with the CUDA Samples in CUDA 5.0, and replaced
>   with helper functions found in NVIDIA_CUDA-5.0/common/inc:
>   helper_cuda.h, helper_cuda_gl.h, helper_cuda_drvapi.h,
>   helper_functions.h, helper_image.h, helper_math.h, helper_string.h,
>   helper_timer.h
>
> These helper functions handle CUDA device
>   initialization, CUDA error checking, string parsing, image file
>   loading and saving, and timing functions. The CUDA Samples projects no
>   longer have references and dependencies to CUTIL, and now use these
>   helper functions going forward.

So you may find useful functions in some of those header files.

Answer (score 1):

in latest SDK helper_math.h implement most of required operator, however its still missing logical operators like OR or AND