# OpenCV: operator "+" error; addition

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem, and i'm not sure why. I need to addition to float3 values.

```
float3 a3 = cross(v1v2,intersection.pIntersect);
a3.normalize();
float3 lambda1 = a3 / (a1+a2+a3);
```

> error: no match for ‘operator/’ in ‘a3 / math::operator+((* &
>   math::operator+((*(const   math::vector*)(& a3)))’

So its not possible to + operate the float3 values. Do I have the wrong type for lambda? or do i miss an operation befor? Or is the normilize() method changing the typ ?

thx for any help :)

Comment: what are you trying to do? dividing a vector by another vector doesn't make a whole lot of sense

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not with **operator+** but with **operator/**

I cannot check the code now, but it seems that you cannot divide two vectors.

EDIT 1

It seems that the compiler is converting the float3 to math::vector for the operator+. After that conversion, it cannot find the operator/(float3, math::vector).

Maybe "cutil_math.h" is not included although it seems that [this header is missing for newer SDKs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919613/where-to-find-cudas-cutil-math-h).

Comment: oh yeah the problem is the operator/. The other part should be right a3 is a triangle ( i have 3)  which i normalize and after that i trying to calculate my lambdas (lambda = Ai / SumOfA's) to calculate my barycentric coordinates. But I think the problem are the types but i'm not sure why