# replacing CUT_CHECK_ERROR and CUT_DEVICE_INIT from cutil.h

Tags: c++, cuda

I recently came across code that includes calls to the functions CUDA_SAFE_CALL, CUT_CHECK_ERROR and CUT_DEVICE_INIT. [note, my question is a general one regarding these kinds of function calls, so I'm not copying the code which is irrelevant here.]

After getting errors on these 3 functions calls, I found that they belong to cutil.h which is no longer a supported library (was used only for SDK examples).
I've found a solution for CUDA_SAFE_CALL which seems to work, here: [What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14038589/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-check-for-errors-using-the-cuda-runtime-api)
However, haven't found yet a solution for the other two functions- CUT_CHECK_ERROR and CUT_DEVICE_INIT.
Do you know of anything that can replace these functions specifically and cutil's functions in general?
Don't know if this is relevant - but I'm using CUDA v 6.0, Visual Studio 2010 and windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can find [replacements in the current CUDA samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919613/where-to-find-cudas-cutil-math-h/14928752#14928752).  This will require some programming ability on your part, the replacements are not exact drop-ins.

Or you can [download a previous cuda SDK package](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive) (e.g. CUDA 4.2) which contains those functions, and [build the necessary libraries under your current toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17969346/cuda-c-library-error-from-cutil-h-to-helper-cuda-h/17981968#17981968).  You should then be able to link against the function directly for a drop-in replacement.