# Global function not recognized by CUDA C

Tags: c++, cuda, nvidia

I have a very complicated program and i have simplified it in order to make my problem easy to understand: I have a 2 scripts and 1 header: *time_analysis.cu*, *DSMC_kernel_float.cu* and *DSMC_kernel_float.h*;

Here is the *time_analysis.cu*

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <math.h>
#include <cutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
#include <cutil_math.h>
#include "math_constants.h"
#include "vector_types.h"
#include "vector_functions.h"

typedef struct {
int seme;
} iniran;

typedef struct{
int jp1;
int jp2;
float kx;
float ky;
float kz;

} stato_struct;

stato_struct* coll_CPU=0;
stato_struct* coll2dev=0;
stato_struct* coll_GPU=0;

#include "DSMC_kernel_float.h"

//==============================================================
int main(void){
int N_thread = 4;
int ind;
coll_CPU[0].jp1= 0;
coll_CPU[1].jp2= 1;
coll_CPU[2].kx= 2;
coll_CPU[3].ky= 3;
coll_CPU[4].kz= 4;

for(ind=0;ind<=5;ind++){
    coll2dev[ind]=coll_CPU[ind];
}

coll2dev=(stato_struct*) malloc(N_thread*sizeof(stato_struct));

CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc((void**)&coll_GPU, N_thread*sizeof(stato_struct)));
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(coll_GPU,coll2dev,N_thread*sizeof(stato_struct), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

CollisioniGPU<<<4,N_thread>>>(coll_GPU);
CUT_CHECK_ERROR("Esecuzione kernel fallita");

CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy(coll2dev, coll_GPU, N_thread*sizeof(stato_struct),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

free(coll2dev);
CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaFree(coll_GPU));

free(coll_CPU);

return 0;
}
```

Here is the *DSMC_kernel_float.cu*

```
// Kernel della DSMC
#include "DSMC_kernel_float.h"

__global__ void CollisioniGPU(stato_struct *coll_GPU){

coll_GPU[0].vAx=1;  
coll_GPU[1].vAy=1;
coll_GPU[2].vAz=1;
coll_GPU[3].tetaAp=1;
coll_GPU[4].phiAp=1;
}
```

Here is the *DSMC_kernel_float.h*

```
__global__ void CollisioniGPU(stato_struct* coll_GPU);
```

However when i type `nvcc -I common/inc -rdc=true time_analysis.cu DSMC_kernel_float.cu` in the terminal I get a weird message error and i don't understand why

```
DSMC_kernel_float.h(1): error: attribute "global" does not apply here

DSMC_kernel_float.h(1): error: incomplete type is not allowed

DSMC_kernel_float.h(1): error: identifier "stato_struct" is undefined

DSMC_kernel_float.h(1): error: identifier "coll_GPU" is undefined

DSMC_kernel_float.cu(4): error: variable "CollisioniGPU" has already been defined

DSMC_kernel_float.cu(4): error: attribute "global" does not apply here

DSMC_kernel_float.cu(4): error: incomplete type is not allowed

DSMC_kernel_float.cu(4): error: expected a ";"

At end of source: warning: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error

8 errors detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00003f1f_00000000-22_DSMC_kernel_float.cpp1.ii".
```

From what I read in the internet, I believe the error is cause by the `struct` but i don't understand how i could fix it to make the program work properly; how is possible that global does not apply here if i have other examples where it seems to be just fine?

Note: *commom/inc* is the folder provided by Nvidia in order to make Cuda compile correctly.

Comment: Ask yourself how the compiler would know the definition of `stato_struct` when it is compiling DSMC_kernel_float.cu?

Comment: do you mean i should use a header file where i define the struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding this statement:

> Note: commom/inc is the folder provided by Nvidia in order to make Cuda compile correctly.

That's a mischaracterization.  The referenced files (cutil.h and cutil_math.h) and macros (e.g. `CUT_CHECK_ERROR`) were provided in fairly old CUDA releases (prior to CUDA 5.0) as part of the *cuda sample codes* that were delivered at that time.  They are *not* required "in order to make Cuda compile correctly."  Furthermore, their use should be considered deprecated (refer to the [CUDA 5.0 toolkit release notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919613/where-to-find-cudas-cutil-math-h/14928752?s=1|0.7100#14928752)).  And if you are actually using an old toolkit like that, I would suggest upgrading to a newer one.

Regarding the compile issues, as @talonmies has pointed out, the compiler has no way of knowing what the definition of `stato_struct` is, when compiling any module that does not contain the definition (whether directly or included).  This would be the case for your `DSMC_kernel_float.cu` module, which is where all your compile errors are coming from.

At first glance, it would seem that a sensible fix would be to move the `typedef` containing the `stato_struct` definition from your time_analysis.cu file into your header file (DSMC_kernel_float.h) and move the `#include` statement for that to the top of the time_analysis.cu file, along with your other includes.

However, it appears that your DSMC_kernel_analysis.cu file believes that there are a variety of members of that `stato_struct`:

```
__global__ void CollisioniGPU(stato_struct *coll_GPU){

coll_GPU[0].vAx=1;  
coll_GPU[1].vAy=1;
coll_GPU[2].vAz=1;
coll_GPU[3].tetaAp=1;
coll_GPU[4].phiAp=1;
}
```

which are *not* part of your current definition of `stato_struct`:

```
typedef struct{
int jp1;
int jp2;
float kx;
float ky;
float kz;

} stato_struct;
```

So this is confusing code, and I don't think anyone else can sort that out for you.  You will either need two separate struct definitions, with separate names, or else you will need to modify your `stato_struct` definition to include those members (`.vAx`, `.vAy`, `.vAz`, `.tetaAp`, `.phiAp`).

The (mis)handling of this struct definition and the resultant errors have nothing to do with CUDA.  This is arising out of the C/C++ language expectations.